# Connecting Ruby to MSSQL server without DBI

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to connect ruby to mssql without using DBI? Is there any native Ruby TDS lib that handles that?

Answer (score 1):

FreeTDS comes to mind, however I have not used it.
Java TDS to MSSQL.

Ruby ODBC or Java ODBC

SOAP using TDS endpoints.

The MSSQL DBI is by far the better out of the lot of them. However I guess if you are running Linux and trying to connect to MSSQL, then try "FreeTDS". There are heaps of tut's and sites to show how to setup and configure for all flavours of Linux.

Comment: I had great success using FreeTDS with [tiny_tds](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds).

Answer (score 0):

I've published an example application how to connect to an MS SQL Server with ruby, you can check it [here](https://github.com/fidalgo/ruby-mssql-example).
It mask use of activerecord-sqlserver-adapter to allow ORM.